# redirect to a controller after successfull login

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am little bit new to MVC. What i want is to redirect the user to Dashboard/Index controller action after successfull Login. What is good place or technique to do so? In ajax success event, or Login controller?

Login form -

```
<form action="/Home/Login" id="loginForm" >
  // other markups
</form>
```

This form is sumitting via jquery ajax-

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#loginForm').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                var url = $(this).attr('action');
                $.post(url, data, function (response) {
                    //redirect from here?
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

JQuery ajax is calling a controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
          //Login successfull.
          //Redirect from here ??
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect form C# code becouse this is called async. You have to redirect from JQuery after success login:

```
window.location.href = "http://site/controller/action";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax to submit,  your server controller will need to return a status response that you would parse in `$.post` callback to determmine whether or not to redirect and then use `window.location` javascript obkect to do redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your authentication/authorization runs on the controller and once that piece of code is   executed with success or failure , you want to move to next view/controller. if this is the intended functionality, the I would suggest you to **RedirectToAction** method and navigate to desired page

More documentation of RedirectToAction can be found here  [Controller.RedirectToAction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: What i suggested was happening at the server side , even before it comes to success event  of the post method